# Nested popups, trouble with popupshowing event

Tags: firefox-addon, dom-events

I'm developing a Firefox extension, and I have a toolbar button that displays an overlay in which I put some XUL code inside `ToolbarDisplayManager`:

```
<overlay id="custombutton-overlay" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

        <toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">
            <toolbarbutton id="boycottToolbarButton" label="Label" tooltiptext="Label" type="menu" popup="ToolbarPopup" />
        </toolbarpalette>
        <popupset>
            <panel id="ToolbarPopup" position="after_start" onpopupshowing="Refresh();">
                <vbox class="ToolbarBody">
                    <box id="ToolbarDisplayManager" />
                </vbox>
            </panel>
        </popupset>
</overlay>
```

Inside "ToolbarDisplayManager" I create a menulist with a menupopup with javascript (like a "combobox") with this structure:

```
<menulist id="combo">
    <menupopup>
        <menuitem>
        <menuitem>
        ...
    </menupopup>
</menulist>
```

Here's the problem:
When I click `ToolbarPopup` I run a "Refresh" function in the `popupshowing` event. But when the overlay is displayed, and I click on the "combo" to select an item, the `popupshowing` event of `ToolbarPopup` is fired again.
In other words: it's like the two "popups" are having troubles with each other.

I need to run the "Refresh" function just before the overlay is shown. Is my structure wrong somewhere? How do I handle two nested popups and their `popupshowing` events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `popupshowing` event bubbles up meaning that it can be intercepted by event handlers higher in the DOM hierarchy than the element triggering the event. So your event handler first receives the `popupshowing` event from the `<panel>` and later another one from the `<menulist>` element (because it is located inside the `<panel>`). You can easily distinguish the two cases using the [`event.eventPhase` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.eventPhase):

```xml
<panel ... onpopupshowing="if (event.eventPhase == Event.AT_TARGET) Refresh();">
```

This will make sure that you ignore events bubbling up and only call `Refresh()` for events that originated in the `<panel>` itself. The other option would have been looking at the [`event.target` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.target).