# How use getSelection?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

How use getSelection?

It does not return the selected text:

```
function pageContextMenu (event) {

    var window = require("sdk/window/utils").getMostRecentBrowserWindow();

    var stringSelection = window.getSelection();
    console.log(stringSelection.toString());
}
    window.document.getElementById("contentAreaContextMenu").addEventListener("popupshowing", pageContextMenu);
```

Comment: Possibly the choice of "popupshowing" as the event to attach is causing side effects due to bubbling of events, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11146648/948073

Comment: In general, you should probably use [sdk/selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/selection) module. Also, I'm not sure what are you trying to do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up content script code and backend/add-on code. Your main.js (backend/add-on) file has access to the SDK modules, your content scripts have access to the DOM (web page/document). If you want to use the DOM api (as you're doing with `getSelection` and `getElementById`) you must do so from the content script side. See [this part of the guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Contributor_s_Guide/Content_Processes) to understand the distinction conceptually. Read [these two tutorials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials#Modify_web_pages) to implement.

If you just want to access the selection from main.js and don't need any other DOM functions, then you'll have to do as @ZER0 suggested and use the `sdk/selection` module